# How can I run python version 3.6.2 instead of 3.6.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

this is my first time here, and I'm fairly new to python, so please let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance.

I am running python 3 on Windows 7

I discovered my problem after I used `pip install numpy`. This works just fine. Then, when I try to use `import numpy` in the python shell I receive the `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'`. That's when I noticed that my default version of python was 3.6.1, despite having updated to 3.6.2 at some point. I still have both .exe setup files and when I run them it shows that I only have 3.6.2 installed. However, when I type `python --version` in the command line i get `Python 3.6.1`, even though Python36-32 is what i have in my path.

I think my question is how can I make sure I'm running the newer version of python as my default, or if need be, how can I get rid of the older version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you type `python` in cmd, it searches `python` command inside the directories in the environment variable named **Path**. Actually **Path** includes both python directory and python scripts directory. For example, in my computer, **Path** includes:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts
```

`pip` is in the python scripts directory. Your **Path** can be wrong. You should check it. [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/6900838) can help you. You should have one python directory and one python script directory in **Path**, just the version you need.

Also, you can call `pip` as a module:

```
python -m pip install numpy
```

This will install the package to the version which is in the **Path**, `Python 3.6.2` in your situation.

If none of these works, I recommend you to uninstall(delete) `Python 3.6.1`, and try to use pip again. If pip doesn't work(or disappeares), you can read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12476379/6900838) or use [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to install pip to your computer again. Maybe, you can delete all python versions, and install the version you need, and of course, you should be careful about **Path** again.

**EDIT:**

I am not sure about your problem. Some informations are needed for a certain solution.

You can find the source of an executable(`python` or `py` in your situtation) with `where` command. Here is an example from my local:

```
where python
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
```

That means `C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\` directory is in my **Path** and when type python, cmd runs `python.exe`.

So, you can find out what are `py` and `python` exactly.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The only thing that worked was 'python -m pip install numpy', and now the 'import numpy' statement is fine. However, it left me more confused. I already had both the python directory and the scripts directory for 3.6.2 in my Path, and there were no other versions there. When I run 'python' in cmd, I'm still getting version 3.6.1. I tried running the python-3.6.1.exe file in order to uninstall, but it only gives me the option to install it while the python-3.6.2.exe file gives my the options 'modify', 'repair', and 'uninstall'. Thanks again! I'll be good for now!

Comment: **Path** is the first thing coming to my mind. I'm glad you're good for now, but this can cause other problems in the future. You need to find a way to solve. Also, just remember when you change an environment variable, you need to close and open again cmd(or IDE) to get updated environment variable.

Comment: I know it's been a while since I posted this, but I discovered something that I don't understand. I'm still having the same issue as before, but I discovered that if I type 'py' in the terminal instead of 'python' I get version 3.6.2 (the one that I wanted). Why is the 'py' command different than 'python?'

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear about what my problem is. The 'import numpy' command works fine now when I run 'py' in the terminal and get version 3.6.2. I just still don't get why 'python' runs 3.6.1.

Comment: @Eyekyu I added extra lines to my answer. I hope it helps. If you can't fix the problem, send me your PATH and the results of `where py` and `where python`.

Comment: what do you get when you run 'which python' from the command line?

Comment: @jmh As far as I know, `which` is a unix command and OP works on Windows 7.

Comment: @Alperen Thanks so much. I figured it out using 'where'. It was much simpler than I realized.I hadn't noticed that my user variables and system variables for python were different. I was just looking at the parts named Python36-32\ but was ignoring the full path. I fixed it by adding the full path to my python executable for the version I wanted in system variables. Again, thank you, and sorry for the trouble.